# If I have to update minecraft will I have to pay for it again?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If I have to update Minecraft will I have to make another purchase? I am scared that I will purchase it again and I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Since Minecraft's first release in 2009, all major content updates have been free to anyone who bought the game. This applies both to the PC and Pocket versions of the game.

I bought the game years ago and am still getting free updates.